# Efficient Methods for Collision Detection Over Long Distances?

Tags: java, 2d, collision, tile, memory-efficient

I have implemented basic collision detection in my top down 2d scrolling game. If the player moves a large distance, it will skip over the areas around it, because the collision detection checks around the player after the movement. As well as this, the player can get stuck in tiles.

I have tried recursively cutting the motion in half to check if it can find a smaller amount of motion that doesn't end in a collision, but I can't seem to get this to work for either problems. It also causes a StackOverflow error.

In the following code, x() represents the player's X location, from the bottom left. y() is the Y location. size is the player's width and height, and prevX and curX are temporary variables. The tiles method gets all tile locations in a certain radius from the player.

```
move(motionx, motiony);
        if (x() - size()/2 < 0)x(size()/2);
        if (y() - size()/2 < 0)y(size()/2);
        if (x() + size()/2 > game.mapWidth * game.chunkWidth * size)x(game.mapWidth*game.chunkWidth*size - size()/2);
        if (y() + size()/2 > game.mapHeight * game.chunkHeight * size)y(game.mapHeight*game.chunkHeight*size - size()/2);
        float curX = x();
        boolean updateX = true;
        boolean updateY = true;
        for (float[] tile : game.tiles((float)Math.ceil((double)size()/(double)size))) {
            Tile t = game.tile(tile[0], tile[1]);
            if (t == null) continue;
            if (t.solid && game.collision(game.coordinate(), tile)) {
                factor(1.0f - t.bounce, 1.0f - t.bounce);
                x(game.prevX);
                updateX = false;
                if (t.solid && game.collision(game.coordinate(), tile)) {
                    x(curX);
                    updateX = true;
                    y(game.prevY);
                    updateY = false;
                    if (t.solid && game.collision(game.coordinate(), tile)) {
                        x(game.prevX);
                        updateX = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (updateX)game.prevX = x();
        if (updateY)game.prevY = y();
```

I hoped this would flawlessly prevent a player from moving onto a solid tile, but it obviously has problems. I am not great at collisions, but am willing to try anything. It sometimes skips over tiles and/or gets stuck.

Comment: Not getting any answers but I don't have enough to create a bounty ;-;.